# adding h2o time remaining to the progress bar during model building

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, h2o

Does anyone know if it is possible to add the time remaining when you use  model.train() in a Jupiter notebook?  The progress bar is nice but it would be even more helpful if this updated with the estimated time remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible (meaning: there is no option to enable that behavior). You are welcome to request this feature in H2O's jira: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa